# PHP PDO SQL Undefinde index : FK_cat;

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

I am trying learn how to create a CRUD.
And stumpled on a undefinde index problem.

> Notice: Undefined index: FK_cat in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\proceskontrol-template\classes\Products.php on line 93

here is my code:

This is my **index.php** I am not sure if there is any problem with this. but as the Notice said the classes\Products.php has an error.

```
<?php   
if (isset($_POST['btn_opret_type'])) {
$name = strip_tags($_POST['type_name']);

if ($name=="") {
    $error[] = "You need a name!";
} else {
    $products->newType($_POST);
    echo'<div class="alert alert-success" data-dismiss="alert" id="myAlert">
    <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>

    Category <b>'.$_POST['type_name'].'</b> has been created!
    </div>';
    // $notification->setNewCategoryNotification();
    // $user->redirect('home');
}
}
?>


<!-- Page-header end -->

<form method="POST" >
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="type_name">Name</label>
        <?=@$error['type_name']?>
        <input type="text" name="type_name" id="type_name" class="form-control" value="<?= @$_POST['type_name'] ?>">
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlSelect4">Category</label>
        <?=@$error['cat_name']?>
        <select class="form-control" name="category[]" id="exampleFormControlSelect4">
            <?php foreach ($products->getAllCategory() as $category) { ?>
                <option value="<?= @$_POST['FK_cat'] ?>" selected><?= @$category->cat_name ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </div>
```

This is the **classes\Products.php** And this is where the error is `':FK_cat' => $post['FK_cat']`
  on the second FK_cat

> **my problem is that i dont know how i should rewrite it.**

```
public function newType($post)
{
    // $newfile = $files;

    return $this->db->query("INSERT INTO `type_tb`(`type_name`, `FK_cat`)
    VALUES (:type_name, :FK_cat)",
        [
        ':type_name' => $post['type_name'],
        ':FK_cat' => $post['FK_cat']
        ]
    );
}
```

and if you need the getALLCategory function then its here:

```
 public function getAllCategory()
{
    return $this->db->toList("SELECT * FROM category_tb");
}
```

I know this may not be the best way to do this but it is the only way i know. Examples on how i should rewrite the classes\Product.php part would be very appreciated

My real index.php

```
<?php
// Start sessions //
ob_start(); // Over buffering start (RAM)
session_start();

// Require config filen //
require_once './config.php';

// Instantisering af objekterne //

    // $upload = new Upload($db);
    $products = new Products($db);
    $notification = new Notifications($db);    
    $setting = new Settings($db);
    // $http = new Http($db);
    // $types = new Type($db);
// $search = new Search($db);

// Inkludere head og menu filerne fra inc mappen //
include_once './includes/head.php';
include_once './includes/menu.php';
// Inkludere vores footer fil fra inc mappen //
 if (isset($_GET['side']) && !empty($_GET['side'])) {
        switch ($_GET['side']) {
// Main pages
        case 'dashboard':
            include('./pages/home.php');
            break;

        case 'dashboard':
            include('./pages/home.php');
            break;

        case 'notifications':
            include('./pages/notifications.php');
            break;

        case 'add':
            include('./pages/add.php');
            break;

        case 'sletProdukt';
            include_once './pages/deleteproduct.php';
            break;

        case 'table':
            include('./pages/table.php');
            break;

        case 'graph':
            include('./pages/graph.php');
            break;

        case 'login':
            include('./pages/login.php');
            break;

        default:
            include('./pages/home.php');
            break;
    }
}
/** Hvis url inputtet er skrevet forkert, rollback til denne */
// } else {
//     header('Location: index.php?side=forside');

include_once './includes/footer.php';
```

Comment: I call it by a Class named Products that is defined in my index

Comment: ohh so i should go like this  return $this->db->query("INSERT INTO `type_tb`(`type_name`, `FK_cat`)
        VALUES (:type_name, :FK_cat)",
            [
            ':type_name' => $post['type_name'],
            ':FK_cat' => $post['cat_name']
            ]
        );?

Comment: I've added my index